# C# Word Count function

Tags: c#

I am new to programming so please bear with me.
Trying to create a word count function.

However, I got the following error:

Below is my code: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'

What does this mean?

```
    private void SplitWords(string fbStatus)
    {
         string[] splitWords = fbStatus.Split(new char[] { ' ' },   
         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: It pretty much means what it says. I presume you know what "implicitly" means? FYI, `string[]` means "array of type string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just change `string[]` to `var` to get this to work. It wants a `string` type variable to store the result in, not a string array - and using `var` tells the compiler to pick the correct type for you so you don't have to worry about it.

Assuming you're not stuck on storing the count in a string, you could use the `Count()` extension method: *(`.Length` will also work, but since you're doing a word count I thought this might be easier to understand)*

```
private void SplitWords(string fbStatus)
{
     int splitWords = fbStatus.Split(new char[] { ' ' },
     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count();
}
```

If you're planning using this value somewhere, you may also want to change `void` to `int` and `return` the value at the end of your method.

```
private int SplitWords(string fbStatus)
{
     return fbStatus.Split(new char[] { ' ' },
     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count();
}
```

Comment: But now, i have to calculate the lexical density. Formulae for it is: Unique word count / Total word count. Assuming that i have this two function, is my this code correct?  private int CalculateLexicalDensity(string fbStatus)
        {
            int ld = 0;
            ld = (UniqueWordCount(fbStatus) / SplitWords(fbStatus)) * 100;

        }

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign the result of `ToString()` (a `System.String`) to a variable of `string[]` type. Simply put, the compiler does not know how to convert the `string` to `string[]` and is complaining.

Perhaps you meant:

```
string numberOfSplitWords = fbStatus.Split(new char[] { ' ' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for a stringified version of the length of an array (i.e. a `string`) but you're trying to store it in a `string[]`. The types don't match, hence the error.

Perhaps you meant:

```
string splitWords = fbStatus
    .Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Length
    .ToString();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The result of

```
fbStatus.Split(
    new char[] { ' ' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
)
.Length
.ToString();
```

is an instance of `string` because `Object.ToString` always returns a `string`. But, you're attempting to assign the result of that to a `string[]` because you said

```
string[] splitWords = fbStatus.Split(
                          new char[] { ' ' },
                          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
                      )
                      .Length
                      .ToString();
```

The compiler would allow you to do this if there were an *implicit* conversion from `string` to `string[]` (*implicit* meaning that you don't have to *explicitly* say "convert this `string` to `string[]`). But, there isn't such an implicit conversion. So, the compiler is telling you that.

> Cannot implicitly convert type `string` to `string[]`

It's not clear to me what you're doing. If you just want the words from the split, you just say

```
string[] splitWords = fbStatus.Split(
                          new char[] { ' ' },
                          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
                      );
```

If you just want the number of words, just say

```
int count = fbStatus.Split(
                 new char[] { ' ' },
                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
            )
            .Length;
```

Based on the *title* of your question, that appears to me to be what you'd want.

Comment: I need the number of words. I did your last int count code but i got the following error:  'int' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Samuel Lee: I don't think that you entered the code correctly because, assuming that `fbStatus` is a `string`, the result of `String.Split` is a `string[]` and all arrays have a `Length` property. Did you accidentally call `Length` twice?

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you an array with the words (a `string[]`):

```
fbStatus.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

This will give you the number of words (an `int`):

```
fbStatus.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length
```

This will give you the number of words converted to string (an `string`):

```
fbStatus.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length.ToString()
```

---

Since that is a `string`, you cannot directly assign it to a `string[]`.